# Capstone Project working with Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I wanted to see if someone could help me with my capstone project. I selected access control and authentication. I need to help a company having issues with employees being able to open vital documents on the company network. I'm using Microsoft Azure to try and fix the problem. I'm trying to outline what I need to do to create a better access control system using a virtual machine in a Windows environment (1 X domain controller, 1 x clients, 4 users) to deliver a solution. I want to look at implementing DAC, RBAC, MAC, or a combination to help protect the essential information. Can anyone please break down a step-by-step process of what I should do? I need the virtual network and set up a topology. I was thinking about the hub-to-spoke topology, but it can change if something is better to use. In 2018, I last worked with Azure and access control, and I feel that I'm jumping around and missing some areas.

Comment: Hey @BigDav had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to first **create a set of virtual networks based on your different office locations** or the assigned location of your employees. The address spaces used for these virtual networks should also be different and not overlap to **avoid policy and access applications** to the other networks. Once done, then **configure the virtual machines for the concerned employees accordingly and the connectivity solution** for them also, i.e., through RDP or Bastion host as such.

•   Then, ensure that the user IDs are created according to the employee’s requirement for access to the Azure resources deployed, i.e., the resources may be Azure file share, blob storage, any Web app created or any certificate, secret in the key vault. Then provide access to the concerned user to that **Azure resource through RBAC (Access control IAM)** by providing the concerned user required access by assigning them roles according to the level of access required for that resource.

•   Also, ensure that you have assigned an Azure role assignment to every user though alike if they are using resources on Azure. In this case, you can create a custom role with the required permissions, actions, and data actions necessary for that Azure role. While doing this, you will also be enrolling your users for Office 365 services to have appropriate access to online office software and mailbox. During which, you will need to opt for **Azure Information Protection license** such that the documents, mails, etc. are protected even after they leave the organization’s domain, i.e., client systems. Also, you would need **Azure AD Premium P2 and Enterprise Mobility + Security (EMS) E5 licenses**.

Thus, in this way, you can set up your organization’s infrastructure in Azure with secure and proper access. Please find below links for more information regarding the specific feature configuration: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-first

The above link describes the use and configuration of Access packages in Azure and how you can use them to create a workflow for approval and requests for assigning the required resources for a particular project in Azure. Similarly, regarding the implementation of Azure Information Protection, kindly refer to the documentation link below for configuration and more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/previous-versions/azure/information-protection/infoprotect-quick-start-tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/faqs